# Data is showing in controller and service but not showing in view

Tags: angularjs, redis, electron

view--index.html it will print  array of data in ng-repeat

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>hii</title>
      <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>


    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <h1>wellcom </h1>


      <p ng-repeat="d in data1 track by $index">{{d}}</p>

      <!--<h3 ng-repeat="d1 in data2"> Type Of data are:  {{d1}}</h3>-->

       </body>

    <script src="controller.js">
        </script>

    <script src="service.js">
        </script>

    </html>
```

This is my service, where I set some data type to Redis server  and I retrieve that data type and return data to controller.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var redis = Promise.promisifyAll(require("redis"));
var client = redis.createClient();

angular.module('myApp')
    .service('redisService', function ($q) {

        this.getAll = function () {
            var a1 = [];
            return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
                //    client.set("string key", "string val", redis.print);
                //     client.hset("hash name", "hashkey 1", "some value", redis.print);
                //     client.hset("hash name", "hashkey 2", "some other value", redis.print);
                //     client.lpush("mylist", "In", redis.print);

                client.scanAsync(0).then(function (data) {

                    data[1].forEach(function (reply) {
                        client.typeAsync(reply).then(function (a) {
                            a1.push(a);


                        })
                    })



                });

                return resolve(a1);
            })

        }

    });
```

This is my controller in this data is coming and printing to  console but data is not setting to view i.e not showing to index.html

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, redisService, $q) {

        $scope.data1;
        redisService.getAll().then(function (data) {
            $scope.data1 = data;
            console.log('data is', $scope.data1)
        })

    })
```

Comment: Could you copy paste the output of console.log($scope.data1) as well?

Comment: Array[0] 0: "hash" 1: "hash" 2: "string" 3: "list" length: 4__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: Array[0] does that mean it's an empty array?

Comment: ok but if Array[o] is empty then how it show the data i.e ''has",''has","string "

Comment: You should try reproduce the problem in a separate example without all the dependencies, like in a jsfiddle entry. It is hard to find where exactly the issue is, when you cannot work on the problem.